# Does a Session Cookie store multiple users data ? (express-session, Passport.js)

Tags: node.js, authentication, cookies, passport.js, express-session

As part of a tutorial I have used `express-session` and `Passport.js` (Local strategy) for authentication of a simple web application.

So when I check the **Request Header while logging in with different users**, I see the same Session ID as the Cookie value:

```
Cookie: connect.sid="some_encrypted_string"
```

**Shouldn't the Cookie be unique for each user?**

But `deserializeUser` callback is being called with different user ids for different users, how is this possible ?

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    // Below line prints different id for each user.
    console.log(`The User ID stored in session store: ${id}`);

    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);  // called by req.isAuthenticated()
    });
});
```

So does `serializeUser` store the id in the same session cookie, or shoud it create a new session cookie for each user ?

How does `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` work?

Comment: Sounds like you're using the same browser to log in as different users concurrently. That won't work. Either test using different browsers, or run one login session from a normal browser window and another login session from a Private Mode/Incognito window.

Comment: @robertklep , Yes I am using same browser to test multiple users. So it is expected to have same cookie for all users in same browser, then how is a user associated with a cookie session ? Is it right to say a session only relates to a browser not a user in database?

Comment: A browser is basically told by a website "when you open this site, send along this cookie". It has no idea what that cookie means, or what it is associated with. My guess is that Express will _replace_ an existing session (for user A) if you log in as another user (user B) inside the same browser. It means you can't log in as two users as the same time from the same browser (unless you use a special browser mode like "guest mode" or "incognito/private mode").